# ¿Cómo se llama este operador || lógico de PHP?

Tags: php

He buscado por todas partes y todos los programadores indican los siguientes operadores `||, &&, OR, AND` etc...

Pero como puedo expresarme de manera hablada mediante su verdadero nombre de signo o símbolo `||`, por ejemplo mediante expresión hablada yo digo doble corchete de apertura y cierre `[]`, los mismo con las llaves `{}`.

Podrían ayudarme.

Comment: if (x == y || x == r), si se da la condición de que 'x' sea igual a 'y' O 'x' sea igual a 'r' entonces haz algo

Comment: es una pregunta demasiado simple que se resuelve con una [busqueda en internet](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php), está pregunta puede ser cerrada

Comment: El operador lógico `||` no es más que un `OR`, a nivel de programación funcionan igual.

Comment: @ReneLimon Amigo ya busque pero todo los llaman operadores lógicos, pero cual es su nombre de este operador, como se llama: `||` ya por ejemplo mediante expresión hablada yo digo doble corchete de apertura y cierre `[]`, los mismo con las llaves {}, etc, pero de esa misma forma como se llama o como se dice `||`

Comment: este | es pipe y este & es ampersand

Comment: @DjCrazy Gracias, sino como puedo explicar mi código al profesor :)

Comment: ya pero cuando estas explicando un IF en "lenguaje humano" ese vendría ser un simple O cuando estas hablando, esta condición O la otra

Comment: Disyunción lógica. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_l%C3%B3gica A pesar de que es interesante, creo que debe ser cerrada la pregunta. Que bueno que se preguntó, que bueno que se trató de contestar pero aún así creo que no cumple con la lógica de este sitio.

Comment: No tendrias problema de explicar el codigo a tu profesor el deberia de saber que es `|` y `||`, no le vas a llegar diciendo: aqui coloque un doble pipe, eso seria un error.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Si tienes razón, pero y para los novatos? :)

Comment: Para los novatos seria lo mismo, por ejemplo: todo el mundo aprende que esto es el arroba `@` ningun novato aprende que ese simbolo es la letra A con una cola en en forma de circulo.

Comment: Esta pregunta realmente no trata sobre programación dentro del ámbito definido en el [help].

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación no hay una diferencia mas que la sintaxis  https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.logical.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el comportamiento es ligeramente distinto, veamos

```
// El resultado de la expression (false || true) es asignado a $e
// Es lo mismo escribir: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// La constante false es asignado a $f y true es ignorado
// Es lo mismo escribir: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;
```

Revisar el concepto de operador de precedencia https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: Amigo pero cual es su nombre de este operador, como se llama: `||` ya  por ejemplo mediante expresión hablada yo digo doble corchete de apertura y cierre `[]`, los mismo con las llaves `{}`, etc, pero de esa misma forma como se llama o como se dice `||`

Comment: Es un operador lógico, podrías llamarlo `O lógico`

Comment: Comun mente al simbolo `|` le dicen pipe.

Comment: SI como dice @OrlandoDeLaRosa podrías llamarlo doble pipe

Comment: Exacto, pero si el nesecita explicar algo del codigo entonce se debe referir a operadores logicos, y no doble pipe.

Answer (score 1):

!, &&, || son operadores lógicos y permiten crear expresiones lógicas más complejas en programación. No obstante estos operadores no solo aplican para la programación puesto que, son utilizados también en álgebra booleana y lógica proposicional.

Pueden ser representados de las siguientes formas:

- Y,   &&,  AND   (Operador lógico de conjunción)
- O,   ||,  OR    (Operador lógico de disyunción)
- NO,  !,   NOT   (Operador lógico de negación)

Como podrás notar, es el mismo operador pero representado de distinta forma.

Tabla de operadores lógicos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

no se si tu pregunta va por aquí pero creo que el operador || es operador OR lógico. O sea si tienes dos operadores y al menos uno de ellos se cumple devolverá True. Ej:

```
Caso 1
condicion1=F
condicion2=T
condicion1||condicion2=T
Caso 2
condicion1=T
condicion2=F
condicion1||condicion2=T
Caso 3
condicion1=T
condicion2=T
condicion1||condicion2=T
Caso 4
condicion1=F
condicion2=F
condicion1||condicion2=F
```

En otras palabras solo devolverá False cuando las dos condiciones lo sean. Espero haberte ayudado. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tomar el tiempo para responder, pero esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta que realizo el OP